# crash when calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When the position of the `UIView`, which contains the `UITableView`, is adjusted, the following `tableview` datasource methods are called:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

but when this method is called :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CommentCell *cell = [[CommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *dic = self._tableViewData[indexPath.row];
    [cell setComment:[dic objectForKey:@"text"]];
    [cell setTimeString:[self commentTimeTransfer:[dic objectForKey:@"create_at" ]]];
    [cell setNickName:[dic objectForKey:@"nick"]];
    NSString * avatarString = [dic objectForKey:@"avatar"];
    NSRange rang = [avatarString rangeOfString:kYoupaiyunURL];
    avatarString = [avatarString substringFromIndex:rang.location + rang.length];
    NSString * urlString = [commonTool fangdaolianUPY:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",avatarString]];
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?_upt=%@",[dic objectForKey:@"avatar"],urlString];

    [cell setImageURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlString]];
    [cell _initViews];

    if (([self._tableViewData count]-1) == indexPath.row) {
        self.lastCommentTime = [[dic objectForKey:@"create_at"] intValue];


  }
    return cell;
}
```

the app crashes. I am sure there is no problem within these methods, but I have no idea what causes this. I need some guidance on what could be causing this.

Comment: What is the crash that is printed on console?

Comment: Please post some more crash log details so that we get an idea about the actual problem.

Comment: you should return of all delegates methods...provide what u did

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: console printing: "libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception".

Answer (score 0):

Possible crash points are

```
[cell setTimeString:[self commentTimeTransfer:[dic objectForKey:@"create_at" ]]];
```

or at

```
if (([self._tableViewData count]-1) == indexPath.row) {
        self.lastCommentTime = [[dic objectForKey:@"create_at"] intValue];
```

Just check Array, Dictionaries are not getting empty or if you are passing any values from this method to another, check there also. Hope your problem will be resolved.

You can do debugging, at which line exactly crash appears.

please share crash details, else no one will be able to help.